# JQuery post not passing variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates

I'm trying to pass an image's src to a django view when a button is clicked.  In my template, I have:

```
$("#url_submit").click(function() {
   var film = "{{ filmname }}"
   var id = {{ id }}
   $.ajax({
     url: "/db/gallery2/" + film + "/" + id + "/",
     data: {url: $('#large_thumbnail').attr('src')},
     type: "POST"
   });  
});
```

My view reads:

```
def thumbnail_choice(request, filmname, id):
    if request.is_ajax:
         if request.method == "POST":
            url = request.POST['url']
            if url != "":
                 mdlnm = get_model('db', filmname.lower())
                 object = get_object_or_404(mdlnm, id__iexact=id)
                 object.url_small = url
                 object.save()
                 return HttpResponseRedirect("/db/")
    return render_to_response('gallery2.html', {'filmname': filmname, 'id': id})
```

When I submit the page though, I get an error:

"Key 'url' not found in `<QueryDict: {}>`"

I'm sure there are a combination of things I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: First thing to do is check with Firebug or TamperData (Firefox plugins) on what exactly is going out in the HTTP request.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Chrome's resources tab in the developer tools.

Comment: When you submit the page? Do you mean you're watching ajax requests in background or actually submitting form by yourself? If the latter is true, then is your form has method="post" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'Oh.  Sorry for wasting your time. Rookie mistake:

```
if request.is_ajax():
```

NOT

```
if request.is_ajax:
```

Thanks for the comments though